# How to manage multiple Slickgrids' events on a page?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, slickgrid, multiple-tables

I have a problem about using multiple Slickgrids on a page. Since the number of grids changes dynamically, I create them in a JavaScript function and use a grid array to keep them like below.

```
var columns = [];
var options = [];
for(var i=0; i<value; i++){
   options[i] = {
    editable: true,
    enableAddRow: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    asyncEditorLoading: true,
    autoEdit: false,
    forceFitColumns: false,
    //fullWidthRows: true,
    syncColumnCellResize: true,
    rerenderOnResize: true,
    topPanelHeight: 30,
    rowHeight: 22,
    cellHighlightCssClass: "changed",
    cellFlashingCssClass: "current-server"};
}
for(var i=0; i<value; i++) {
   columns[i].push({id: value, name: value, field: value});
   columns[i].push({id: value2, name: value2, field: value2});
   columns[i].push({id: value3, name: value3, field: value3});
}
var arrayOfGrids = [];

for(var i=0; i<value; i++) {
  dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
  arrayOfGrids.push(new Slick.Grid('#' + i, dataView, columns[i], options[i]));
    // ....
```

But my problem is how I manage these grids' events because the events should be implemented separately as far as I concerned. Even if my all grids must have the same events, I don't know how I can determine which grid's event is triggered.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the concept of closures in Javascript? If not you should google it.

Here is how I think they can solve your problem:

1) create an own function to create/initialize your grid

2) call this function in your for-loop

3) subscribe to your events in the initGrid function. This way you will always have a reference to the correct grid. (Have a look at the comments in the initGrid function in my code below)

```
function initGrid(index)
{
  var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
  var grid = new Slick.Grid('#' + index, dataView, columns[index], options[index]);
  arrayOfGrids.push(grid);
  grid.onClick.subscribe(function (e) {
     //grid variable will always be the clicked gird
     //index variable will always be the correct one for this grid
     //columns[index] will always be the columns for the clicked grid
     //...
  });
}

for(var i=0; i<value; i++) {
    initGrid(i);
    // ....
}
```